# Selenium Select Can't locate options

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having an issue when I locate and assign a Select object grabbing its options, probably due to some of the wonky HTML on the page.  Here is the HTML of the Select and its options:

```
<select>
<option selected="" val="1">1</option>
<option val="2">2</option>
<option val="3">3</option>
<option val="4">4</option>
<option val="5">5</option>
...
</select>
```

The select is located using XPath as such: `.//*[@id='employeeTable_paginate']/div/select`

I am wondering if it isn't able to locate the options since the `values` are referred to as `vals` in the HTML?  I tried the following code to see if it would get the Options:

`for (WebElement option : select.getOptions()) System.out.println(option);`

but it does not print anything.  Additionally, if I try to select an option by index, it says it can not locate option with that index.

Answer (score 1):

selectByValue would definitely not work in that case. If you go to the [implementation of Select](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.java), you can see that `selectByValue()` uses xpath to find the `value` field. The good news is that it's an easy fix.

For your case, you'll want to find the single value (searching for `val` instead), and select it.

```
WebElement option = element.findElement(By.xpath(
        ".//option[@val = '" + value + "']"));

if (!option.isSelected())
{
    option.click();
}
```

I'm not sure why selectByIndex doesn't work, can you check the count of `select.getOptions()`? It's always possible the select object is just incorrect.

Comment: So, `select.getOptions().size()` gives me a result of 0.  This doesn't make sense to me since the Select option is found using `Select select = new Select(SeleniumCommands.waitFindByXpath(".//*[@id='employeeTable_paginate']/div/select"));`  I confirm this is the correct selection method because if I use my method for clicking this element, it will click it correctly.  Does this not conform to a proper Select object?  That's the only thing I can think...

Comment: Also, I would just like to mention that `.//option[@val = " + Quotes.escape(value) + "]"` did not work for me, though I did use `\"` instead of your `Quotes` object.

Comment: @Imcphers Quotes should be under org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Quotes but I'll change it anyways. Your way works too, another option it use single quotes.

Comment: @Imcphers Is this new select working though? It's odd that the getOptions() is empty, can you check the website and verify that the options' tag names are 'option', that they have correct indexes, and that this whole thing is not in an iframe?

Comment: Yup, the tags are "options".  For some reason when I originally copy and pasted the HTML, it wasn't "exact", but I corrected it.  It's mostly the same, just includes the values that go inside the Options.  It's not in an iFrame because I can click the Select object and then click the Option by direct Xpath.  I just can't seem to get it to work with Select objects because I was running into strange behavior when clicking the Option by XPath, so I wanted to try it this way to see if I get the same behavior.

Comment: @Imcphers Sorry, for clarification, does each individual option have the tag name `option` or `options`, if it's the former then I'm not sure what's wrong, if it's the latter then it should be an easy fix.

Comment: `<option val="1">1</option>
...`
This is what they all look like.